# Backup Evernote to Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, synchronization, backup, evernote, file-conversion

I want to...

- automatically perform a *one way sync* from Evernote to Dropbox
- convert the notes to a format supported by [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) or HTML during the synchronization. But any non proprietary and easily editable format will do!

The solution is better if...

- I can pick the destination folder freely
- the destination format is supported by LibreOffice, as it's my preferred office suite.
- the destination format is ODF/OpenDocument, as it's my preferred free and open office suite format
- it detects which notes are new, deleted and updated so it doesn't have to synchronize everything each time
- the same solution can handle other similar use cases, such as [doing the same thing for Google Drive instead of Evernote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37810/backup-google-drive-to-dropbox)

It doesn't matter whether the solution is free of charge or has a reasonable price.

Answer (score 4):

[CloudHQ](https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox) is a paid service that supports [one-way syncing](https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox/unidirectional-synchronization-dropbox-basecamp-google-docs-in-real-time) between a variety of cloud platforms

I can't comment on whether or not the output would be supported by LibreOffice or HTML, but it seems likely that it would. I would email the developers.