# Backup Google Drive to Dropbox

Tags: google-drive, dropbox, synchronization, backup, file-conversion

I want to...

- automatically perform a *one way sync* from Google Drive to Dropbox
- convert the files to a format supported by [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) or HTML during the synchronization. But any non proprietary and easily editable format will do!

The solution is better if...

- I can pick the destionation folder freely
- the destination format is supported by LibreOffice, as it's my preferred office suite.
- the destination format is ODF/OpenDocument, as it's my preferred free and open office suite format
- it detects which files are new, deleted and updated so it doesn't have to synchronize everything each time
- the same solution can handle other similar use cases, such as [doing the same thing for Evernote instead of Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37809/backup-evernote-to-dropbox)

It doesn't matter if...

- the solution is free of charge or has a reasonable price

Comment: See my answer to your other question.

Answer (score 1):

[Brive](https://github.com/x8wk/Brive) does this. Will backup all your documents in a variety of formats.